# Where are decoration (scale bar, etc) plug-ins in QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis

For QGIS 1.8 what happened to the "Decorations" (North Arrow, Scale Bar, etc.) plug-in (for the canvas, not composer)?

Answer (score 4):

The decoration plugin (scale bar, noth arrow, label ..) has been merged to the core application.

You can access them from the menu : *View > Decorations*